# How can I calculate pitch value with gyroscope in MPU9250 of Navio2 (python2)

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, sensors, gyroscope, robotics

I can obtain raw values of gyro sensor.

But, I don't know how to calculate the pitch value with these values.

I want to get pitch value between -180 and +180.

This is because I want to obtain a precise pitch value using a complementary filter with a pitch value obtained with an accelerometer and a pitch value obtained with a gyroscope.

Please help me.

---

**My Code (obtain raw values of gyro sensor)**

```
import spidev
import time
import argparse
import sys
import navio.mpu9250
import navio.util

navio.util.check_apm()

imu = navio.mpu9250.MPU9250()
imu.initialize()

m9a, m9g, m9m = acc.imu.getMotion9()

#These are raw values of gyroscope
gyro_x = m9g[0]
gyro_y = m9g[1]
gyro_z = m9g[2]
```

---

**Detail(setting)**

*gyro_scale = 2000DPS*

*gyro_divider = 16.4*

'raw values of gyro sensor' = (PI/180)*data/gyro_divider

[image]

---

[**Reference code.**](https://github.com/emlid/Navio2/blob/master/Python/navio/mpu9250.py#L350)

```
...

def getMotion9(self):
    self.read_all()
    m9a = self.accelerometer_data
    m9g = self.gyroscope_data
    m9m = self.magnetometer_data

    return m9a, m9g, m9m

...

def read_all(self):
    # Send I2C command at first
    # Set the I2C slave addres of AK8963 and set for read.
    self.WriteReg(self.__MPUREG_I2C_SLV0_ADDR, self.__AK8963_I2C_ADDR | self.__READ_FLAG)
    # I2C slave 0 register address from where ; //Read 7 bytes from the magnetometerto begin data transfer
    self.WriteReg(self.__MPUREG_I2C_SLV0_REG, self.__AK8963_HXL)
    # Read 7 bytes from the magnetometer
    self.WriteReg(self.__MPUREG_I2C_SLV0_CTRL, 0x87)
    # must start your read from AK8963A register 0x03 and read seven bytes so that upon read of ST2 register 0x09 the AK8963A will unlatch the data registers for the next measurement.

    # time.sleep(0.001)
    response = self.ReadRegs(self.__MPUREG_ACCEL_XOUT_H, 21);

    # Get Accelerometer values
    for i in range(0, 3):
        data = self.byte_to_float(response[i*2:i*2+2])
        self.accelerometer_data[i] = self.G_SI*data/self.acc_divider

    # Get temperature
    i = 3
    temp = self.byte_to_float(response[i*2:i*2+2])
    self.temperature = (temp/340.0)+36.53

    # Get gyroscope values
    for i in range(4, 7):
        data = self.byte_to_float(response[i*2:i*2+2])
        self.gyroscope_data[i-4] =(self.PI/180)*data/self.gyro_divider

    # Get magnetometer values
    for i in range(7, 10):
        data = self.byte_to_float_le(response[i*2:i*2+2])
        self.magnetometer_data[i-7] = data * self.magnetometer_ASA[i-7]
```

Comment: Gyros measure angular change over time so the raw values represent that for all three dimensions (yaw, pitch, roll). To get an angle you need to sample your data over a period of time and calculate the change since you started sampling. Then you need to keep updating that state if you want to know the angle difference between the 'calibration' stage (sampling at 0 degrees) and the current state.

Comment: Does that mean that the angle at which sampling starts should be zero degrees?
what if the actual sampling start angle is not 0° C ?

Comment: You cannot know if you started sampling at 0° or not - as I said, gyros give you angle change over time - for picking up the current angle (in respect to gravity) you need an inclinometer. With gyro only, you to define a reference point for calibration (btw. same goes for accelerometers, just with a position change over time instead of an angle) by standing still at what you'll call `0°` position. Of course, due to inevitable errors in sampling rate of the gyro itself and your code it will start 'drifting' over time and require re-calibration once in a while.